# javascript while loop doesn't end

Tags: javascript, string, if-statement, while-loop, substring

I'm trying to run the following `while` loop in `JavaScript`:

```
function returnSubstring(i, theString) {
    var j = 1;
    while (i > 1) {
        if (theString.charCodeAt(j) == ',') {
            i--;
        }
        else {
            <% System.out.println("nope, not a comma"); %>
        }
        j++;
    }
    var value = theString;
    var subString = value.substring(j, value.indexOf(",", j+1));
    alert(subString);       
}
```

and I just pass an *index* and `string`

```
returnSubstring(someIndex, someString);
```

It keeps crashing. I think i atleast get one round in the `while` loop. (I get 1 `'nope'`)
What am I doing wrong here?

also when index is 0 or 1 it works. but other numbers, no

Comment: Learn to use your browser's debugging tools.

Comment: Well, what happens when the string doesn't contain a comma? Also, do you get an error or an infinite loop?

Comment: You don't decrement `i` in the else statement.

Comment: @Johnny5 I'm using `i` to determine where I want to stop at. each time I find a comma it's 1 less comma to my goal hence `i--`

Comment: System.out.println is java, not  JavaScript. And what is `<÷` ? I think that's an escape for server side, like asp/php.

Comment: `j` should start at 0, and `i` **must** ALWAYS be decremented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should ALWAYS decrement `i`, otherwise you will never end your loop, and J will be out of bounds. Also... you should `var j = 0`, otherwise you will skip the first character.

For example: `"Text"`, and `i == 2`

You start at:
`"T"`, no comma, move `j` forward, `i` still 2.
`"e"`, no comma, move `j` forward, `i` still 2.
`"x"`, no comma, move `j` forward, `i` still 2.
`"t"`, no comma, move `j` forward, `i` still 2.
`""(empty string)`, no comma, `j` is now out of bounds, move `j` forward, `i` still 2.
^ This last step gets repeated forever.

Instead, change your code to:

```
function returnSubstring(i, theString) {
    i = i > theString.length() ? theString.length() : i; // don't go too far.
    var j = 0; // Start at 0
    while (i >= 1) { // `i > 1` is stopping the code 1 character earlier
        if (theString.charCodeAt(j) != ',') { // this `if` is not required
            console.log("nope, not a comma"); // No JAVA code, please
        }
        i--;
        j++;
    }
    var value = theString;
    var subString = value.substring(j, value.indexOf(",", j+1));
    // alert(subString); // not necessary
    return subString; // return the value
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should decrement **i**

Are you sure you can do this:

```
<% System.out.println("nope, not a comma"); %>
```

Why don't you use:

```
document.write()
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't decrement `i` if the character at `i` is not a comma. I recommend to use a for loop so that `i` gets decremented no matter what's in the loop: `for (; i > 1; i--)`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that your loop iterates through the input string, something like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < theString.length; i++) { ... }
```

That would prevent a number of logical errors that would result in an infinite loop.